# Why i can't kill Erlang process?

Tags: process, erlang, exit

I am spawning 2 processes and it seems i can not kill either of them:

- `restarter` - process that spawns the `worker` whenever it goes down
- `worker` -process that gets messages from the shell, concatenates them and returns them in the `reason` of an exit to the restarter which in turn forwards them to the shell.

The `worker` process can't be killed since the `restarter` would restart it on any trap exit message. But what keeps the `restarter` process alive?

```
-module(mon).
-compile_flags([debug_info]).
-export([worker/1,init/0,restarter/2,clean/1]).

% ctrl+g
init()->
    Pid=spawn(?MODULE,restarter,[self(),[]]),
    register(restarter,Pid),
    Pid.


restarter(Shell,Queue)->
    process_flag(trap_exit,true),

    Wk=spawn_link(?MODULE,worker,[Queue]),
    register(worker,Wk),

    receive

        {'EXIT',Pid,{Queue,normal}}->Shell ! {Queue,"From res: worker died peacefully, wont restart"};

        {'EXIT',Pid,{Queue,horrible}} ->
                Shell ! {Queue,"Processed so far:"},
            Shell ! "will restart in 5 seconds, select fresh/stale -> 1/0",
            receive
                1 -> 
                    Shell ! "Will restart fresh",
                    restarter(Shell,[]);
                0 ->Shell ! "Will continue work",
                    restarter(Shell,Queue)
            after 5000 ->
              Shell ! "No response -> started with 666",
              restarter(Shell,[666]) 
            end;
        {MSG}->Shell ! {"Unknown message...closing",MSG}
end.


worker(Queue)->

    receive 
        die->exit({Queue,horrible});
        finish->exit({Queue,normal});
        MSG->worker([{time(),MSG}|Queue])
    end.
```

**Usage**

```
mon:init().
regs().  %worker and restarter are working
whereis(worker) ! "msg 1", whereis(worker) ! "msg2".
whereis(worker) ! finish.
flush().  % should get the first clause from restarter 
regs().  % worker should be up and running again
exit(whereis(restarter),reason).
regs().  % restarter should be dead
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenario, the `restarter` process is trapping exits, so `exit(whereis(restarter), reason)` doesn't kill it.  The exit signal gets converted to a message, and gets put into the message queue of the process:

```
> process_info(whereis(restarter), messages).
{messages,[{'EXIT',<0.76.0>,reason}]}
```

The reason it's still in the message queue is that none of the clauses in the `receive` expression matches this message.  The first two clauses are specific to the exit reasons used by the `worker` process, and the last clause might look like a catch-all clause but it actually isn't - it matches any message that is a tuple with one element.  If it were written `MSG` instead of `{MSG}`, it would have received the exit reason message, and sent "Unknown message" to the shell.

If you really want to kill the process, use the `kill` reason:

```
exit(whereis(restarter), kill).
```

A `kill` exit signal is untrappable, even if the process is trapping exits.

---

Another thing: the first two receive clauses will only match if the worker's queue is empty.  That is because it reuses the variable name `Queue`, so the queue in `{'EXIT',Pid,{Queue,normal}}` must be equal to the value passed as an argument to the `restarter` function.  In a situation like this, you'd normally use `NewQueue` or something as the variable in the receive clauses.

Comment: But reading from `LYAE` i understood that `exit/2` is used as  a trigger to kill processes.I do not understand , you can only kill processes with the `kill` as `reason` in when using `exit/2` ?

Comment: It works fine as long as the process you're trying to kill is not trapping exits.